# GET API request to multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, frontend

**Problem:**
I have 47 urls, all of which only differ by their last one/two characters, 1-47.

Example:
https://example.com/api/data?number=1    <--- the last digit range from 1 to 47

I need to make API GET request to each of them for their data, so I can plot them.

**What I have so far:**

```
let exampleLink = 'https://example.com/api/data?code='

let data = []

const req = new XMLHttpRequest()

for(let i=1; i<48; i++){
  req.open('GET', exampleLink + i, true)
  req.send();

  req.onload = () => {
    let result = JSON.parse(req.responseText)
    data.push(result)
  }
}
```

This is not working for me, the FOR loop only end up giving me the last result #47.

Would anyone know how to make such request and push response data into array?

Many thanks,

Codey

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to solve this.
In this case, to fast fix this, you can use local variable inside for loop, as currently you override the request everytime.

```
let exampleLink = 'https://example.com/api/data?code='

let data = []

for(let i=1; i<48; i++){
  let req = new XMLHttpRequest()
  req.open('GET', exampleLink + i, true)
  req.send();

  req.onload = () => {
    let result = JSON.parse(req.responseText)
    data.push(result)
  }
}
```

Comment: This directly solved my question, thank you. The problem I'm experiencing now is, I can't really do anything with this data since it's in the FOR loop, therefore I think my approach to this question isn't correct. My goal is to plot 47 url's data on a graph, hence I will end up with 47 lines/data, each representing the population of a city.

Comment: Decided to use axios and setState to record API response, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Its normal that its giving you the last result, your code is in Javascript, try to use a Async function, something like this(axios for the request its a great node package you should look it up) :

```
for(let i=1; i<48; i++){
source = url +`&page_size=${i}`
async function ResourcesFetcher() {
await axios.get(source).then((results ) => {
//the do whatever action you want to 
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I looked up axios and considering using it since I have to use react.js for my project. In the API I have for the 47 urls, I have one API KEY (password) in which I need to input in order to access the API data, how would you input the API KEY for axios? I know how to do it for XHR but not axios.

Comment: I figured it out, axios.get(one, {headers: config}), and config is an object containing username and password like {"yourname": "yourpassword"}, but thanks anyways.

Comment: sorry didnt get the notification, good to see you fixed  it :)